# Construct URL by passing one string at a time and print response - Java

Tags: java

HI i am trying to find gender for person firstnames(20 names) by using website.....

First i am extracting xml elements in the format "start:234 stop:543 annotation:john". So i am reading the text contents of particular element split with space delimiter and pass to vector(NameBuffer class is dong that).
Now i have all elemets as vector objects. In order get only annotation(where the required names lies) i am iterating vector fn and reading string using fn.annotation like the following

```
NameBuffer fln = null;  
    String[] names=null;  
    Vector<NameBuffer> fullNameVector = Execute.readNames(new File("/abc.xml"), "fullname");//Reading xml element split and put as vector object  
    Iterator itr1 = fullNameVector.iterator();  
    while(itr1.hasNext())  
    {  
        fln=(NameBuffer) itr1.next();  
        String st1 = fln.toString();  
        NameBuffer fn= new NameBuffer(st1); //NameBuffer class constructor  takes each object in vector and split each object and returns contents like fn.start is 234,fn.stop is 543.fn.annotation is john....  

        URL url = new URL("http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?name=fn.annotation");  
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    try {  
        // Create connection  

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");  
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
        connection.setUseCaches(false);  
        connection.setDoInput(true);  
        connection.setDoOutput(true);  
        connection.connect();  

        // Get Response  
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();  
        int status = connection.getResponseCode();  
        //System.out.println(status);  

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
        String line;  
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {  
         if(line.contains("It's a boy!"))  
                 {  
             System.out.println(fn.annotation+"is Male");  
                 }  
         if(line.contains("It's a girl!"))  
         {  
             System.out.println(fn.annotation+"is Female");  
         }  


        }  

        rd.close();
```

So fn.annotation returns all names but when i pass it as parameter to url the request did not sent with actual name....
Is it a syntax mistake or do i need to do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Your url should be

```
"http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?name=" + fn.annotation
```

Am I right ?

Comment: It's always a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly the way your NameBuffer class works, you should be doing:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?name=" + fn.annotation);
```